# Receiving werid error when lauching forge through Intellij on Mac OS

Tags: java, macos, intellij-idea, minecraft-forge

[image: The error in question]

Here is the error i am getting. I tried to google it but i found nothing and i have no idea how to fix it. Please can anyone help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/37579227/104891.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I did and i shall look through my code to find if something like this exists. Only if i knew where to look..

Comment: You are using some weird JDK that may override OS name. Try a different JDK version/vendor.

Comment: I shall try this now thank you!

Comment: Yeah i had some weird JDK indeed. Fixed it now by installing openjdk! Thank you!

Comment: @vassdeniss Please click the gray checkmark to the left of Crazy Coder's answer to mark it as accepted. The checkmark will change colors from gray to green when it is clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using some weird JDK which may override or not detect the OS name properly. Using OpenJDK should help.